# Tslint force use to access modifiers and space between function

Tags: tslint

Hello guys I want to use a mandatory space between each function declaration and also to force the developer to use access modifiers (Public, Private, Protected) each time I declare a method or variable.

```
**For instance:**

    private my_var;
    private myFunction() {}

// one space between function.
    private myFunction() {}
```

I have this rules in my tslint.json file but it is not working.

```
{
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/codelyzer"
  ],
  "rules": {
  "member-access": true,
  "typedef-whitespace": [true,
    { "call-signature": "onespace" }
  ],
}
```

Thank you very much.